# Fail to install source with dpkg-source

Tags: kernel, dpkg, source-code

I need to install kernel source for 3.19.0-73.
I downloaded the 3 packages from

```
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-vivid/3.19.0-73.81~14.04.1

linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0.orig.tar.gz  
linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81-14.04.1.diff.gz  
linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81-14.04.1.dsc
```

From what I understand:
`linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0.orig.tar.gz` - is the original kernel.
`linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81-14.04.1.diff.gz` - contains the difference.
`linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81-14.04.1.dsc -t dpkg`-source receive as input and instruction how to apply patch.

When running

```
dpkg-source -x linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81-14.04.1.dsc
```

I get error:

```
error: cannot fstat file ./linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81~14.04.1.diff.gz: No such file or directory
```

I see that in the site they write file linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81-14.04.1.diff.gz is 11 MB, and on my disc it is 49MB after downloading.

Maybe this is the problem ?

**Full logs:**

```
root@quantastor:/home/ilan/test# ls -la
total 169568
drwxrwxr-x 2 ilan ilan      4096 Apr  9 01:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 ilan ilan      4096 Apr  9 00:57 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ilan ilan  50315517 Apr  9 01:33 linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81-14.04.1.diff.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ilan ilan      8272 Apr  9 01:35 linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81-14.04.1.dsc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ilan ilan 123115155 Apr  9 01:33 linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0.orig.tar.gz
root@quantastor:/home/ilan/test# dpkg-source -x linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81-14.04.1.dsc
gpgv: Signature made Tue 18 Oct 2016 03:23:31 PM PDT using RSA key ID 2DB9F73A
gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found
dpkg-source: warning: failed to verify signature on ./linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81-14.04.1.dsc
dpkg-source: error: cannot fstat file ./linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81~14.04.1.diff.gz: No such file or directory
root@quantastor:/home/ilan/test#
```

Comment: I don't know if that matters, but in `error: cannot fstat file ./linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81~14.04.1.diff.gz` it is a different file-name, tilde is used instead of a dash.

Comment: The file-names in https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-vivid/3.19.0-73.81~14.04.1 also use the tilde instead of a dash. I'd rename the filenames accordingly and run dpkg-source again.

Comment: re-download the .diff, it should only be this size, `11745488 Apr  9 08:40 linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81~14.04.1.diff.gz`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest you to use `apt` or `apt-get` utility to download and extract source files.

`--download-only` will download all three file for you and makes sure they are okay. at my xenial:

```
apt-get source --download-only linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic
```

`--download` is same as `--download-only` and it will extract the source for you.

```
apt-get source --download linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic
```

Just `cd` to the directory where your downloaded files are, and try using `apt` or `apt-get`, if something is wrong with them, it will try to download them again.

Anyway, it seems that something is wrong with your:

```
linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81-14.04.1.diff.gz
```

Again I recommend to use `apt` or `apt-get`, however you should download this  file and verify that it has been downloaded correctly.

To do that run:

```
sha1sum linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81-14.04.1.diff.gz
```

It should return:

```
a94c660c4e15f6a950573c11618a04094eacc652
```

Then try to extract it using `dpkg-source -x`, if it did not work, rename:
`linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81-14.04.1.diff.gz`
to:
`linux-lts-vivid_3.19.0-73.81~14.04.1.diff.gz`, (Not sure but give it a try).

Answer (score 1):

The fstat error states that it's looking for a file and is unable to find it. Make sure you have downloaded all the files in the same folder and then run your commands. The missing public key is probably in /root. See the following:

http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=69201

Answer (score 0):

Add the public key to your system by using the key ID returned in the error message:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 2DB9F73A
```

Also use the key server of your distro.